# cPickle, Pickle load EOFError in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pandas, pickle

I am trying to read a pickle file 'file.pkl' in windows.

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import cPickle as cpkl
data = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')
```

but I get the error:
     raise EOFError

This happens also if I try

```
import cPickle as cpkl
data = cpkl.load(open('file.pkl','rb'))
```

If I run this on linux there is no problem.
How can I read this file on windows?

Thanks

Comment: How did you create the pickle file (was it created in pandas?), can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: No I just receive the file from an old project without any info of the file.

Comment: Have you tried python 2 and 3? If it's not created by pandas you won't be able to open it with pandas...

Comment: I used python 2.7 with anaconda, the second try was without pandas.

Comment: pickling is different on different version of python, you should try in on python 3 too (not sure about pandas backwards compatibility).

Comment: @shx2 not sure this is a dupe, as I think the file was opened correctly (rb).

Comment: @AndyHayden while the question is not identical, it is very similar, and the answer applies to both (it addresses how to write, read, and how to convert an already-badly-written file).

Comment: I tried following the advice of the alleged original of this dup, got the same error, even with 'rb' as an argument. I think this is a different problem.